# Cannot take picture with Canon SX 510 powershot connected to Pi3 via gphoto2

Tags: pi-3

when I execute this:

```
gphoto2 --trigger-capture
```

This returns:

```
*** Error ***
Sorry, your camera does not support generic capture
ERROR: Could not trigger capture.
*** Error (-6: 'Unsupported operation') ***

For debugging messages, please use the --debug option.
Debugging messages may help finding a solution to your problem.
If you intend to send any error or debug messages to the gphoto
developer mailing list <gphoto-devel@lists.sourceforge.net>, please run
gphoto2 as follows:

    env LANG=C gphoto2 --debug --debug-logfile=my-logfile.txt --trigger-capture

Please make sure there is sufficient quoting around the arguments.
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. As the message says: the SX 510  does not support generic capture.

If you want a camera to do the capture, choose a camera that supports it. Look  at http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php for a camera with Image Capture.